# How to enable Visual studio 2013 intellisense for uncompiled class members

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I was using visual studio 2008 before and whenever i add a new class or class member in a project referenced by my main project, it will appear in autocomplete feature (by pressing Ctrl+Space or by writting dot "." after instance name). Now i am using visual studio 2013 and i have to compile referenced project everytime if i add a member in class. Only then it will appear in intellisense.

How can i get same behaviour as in visual studio 2008? or is it not possible in visual studio 2013?

Comment: Do you have any compiler errors? If the code is compilable, then visual studio will compile it in background and it will show up in intellisense.

Comment: I know it should work like this and it was working this way in Visual studio 2008. But in Visual studio 2013 its not working. Code is compilable. Its perfectly fine. And now i am changing one variable name, and it is not reflecting in the project where i referenced this code.

Comment: One more thing. I installed visual studio 2013 without internet conenction. And after installation, there were some errors related to certifcates and it says that there will be issues in some components. May be this is the cause ? and i need to isntall it on machine when internet conenction is available ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem.See if that's not working in all projects or your project alone. Try it in some other sample application.

Comment: I installed Windows 7 updates. updated IE explorer to v11. And now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 was newly installed on my machine. I installed Windows 7 updates. updated IE explorer to version 11 (previously it was version 8). And now its working fine.